# What shows the following features in Shipping Settings in nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

What shows the following option in Shipping Settings in nopcommerce

i.e. 
1. Use warehouse location
2. Notify customer about shipping from multiple locations if required
3. Display shipment events (customers)
4. Display shipment events (store owners)
5. Bypass shipping method page.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in its documentation [here](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/Shipping+Settings)

> - Tick **Use warehouse location** to use it when requesting shipping rates.    This is useful when you ship from multiple warehouses.
> - Tick **Notify customer** about shipping from multiple locations if    required. This is useful when you ship from multiple warehouses.
> - Tick **Display shipment events (customers)**, to enable customers to view    shipment events on their shipment details page. Note: to be
>     enabled,    this feature must be supported by a shipment computation
>     method
> - Tick **Display shipment events (store owners)**, to enable store owners    to view shipment events on their shipment details page.
>     Note: to be    enabled, this feature must be supported by a shipment
>     computation    method
> - Tick **Bypass shipping method page** if there's only one shipping method    available. This page will not be displayed during the
>     checkout    process.

Comment: But, I want to tell that by enable this type of option then at client side where it is showing?